# Running Kallithea in Docker on Synology Server

Tags: git, nas, docker

I am attempting to set up a git server with https://kallithea-scm.org/ in a docker image. The installation went through fine. I started the kallithea server and the terminal says,

```
serving on http://127.0.0.1:5678
```

Lets assume my docker host is 192.168.1.2, I should be able to access the kallithea server with `192.168.1.2:5678`, correct? Well, I am getting

```
This webpage is not available
```

Is there something I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you configured Kallithea to listen on 127.0.0.1 (with a line containing `host = 127.0.0.1` in its `.ini` file), you can only access it via the host's/Docker container's loopback interface, i.e. it's not accessible from other hosts. To make it accessible, you could add a port mapping to the Docker environment with something like this in your Docker configuration:

```
ports:
  - "5678:5678"
```